# Some facebook tabs doesn't show for all users

Tags: facebook

I have a page with 7 custom application I've made, tested and are currently attacked to a facebook page. For some users they see all 7 application, other users see only 1. The applications are in iFrame, with sandbox disabled. From my computer using my account and my sister's account (FF/Chrome) - we both see all of them, in Opera without login I also see all of the applications. What could be the cause?

Here is the page: https://www.facebook.com/pages/Gloria-Mar/267571689965042

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested viewing in various browsers with both "developers" and non- facebook developer accounts and I can always see 7 apps listed.  I'm not sure how to reproduce this issue.  Can you give specifics on how to reproduce?

Comment: This is the entire "problem" - there is no problem. We just have feedback from users where they state that they see either 1, a few applications or in my case see them all. All of the current applications are with site/tab/facebook app options enabled from developer menus. They are entirely the same, with different URL and main settings being different ofcourse. Like you, I have tested with different account types, but I always see them and they work normally.

Comment: It appears that when I turn off the secure browsing, I don't see any of the application, except one. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Of course, you need to have both http and https setup for each of the apps.  :)  Good find.

Comment: You are correct, thank you. Apologize that I didn't mark it sooner.