# Facebook custom tab not visible for everyone?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I've a fan page which has 2 custom tabs (lets call them "catalogo" and "rifa"), problem is that one of them only shows to certain people on a seemly random basis.

As far as the settings is concerned, both were created with identical settings on the same day. The both pull content from the same server (http://flor360.com) and secure and non-secure versions from Tab URL are correct and verified to be accessible.

What puzzles me it that just some users are able to see the "rifa" tab, but everyone is able to see the "catalogo" one.

It's reproducible 100% of the time if you sign out of FB and visit https://www.facebook.com/floristeria.flor360 you will only see the "catalogo" tab but if you log to FB and visit the same page again, if you're "lucky" you see both tabs, "catalogo" and "rifa".

I've been trying different settings all day but it just look like a FB bug to me, I've read the following related topics:

[Some facebook tabs doesn't show for all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700907/some-facebook-tabs-doesnt-show-for-all-users)

developers.connect.facebook.com/bugs/250648431689434/?browse=search_4f4fde5e1c9a43429488828

developers.beta.facebook.com/bugs/257675740992709/?browse=search_4f7f3b8ff0a253393699815

[sorry they're not URL, StackOverflow though it was SPAM]

But it's not any of those suggestions (SSL is OK and changing "secure browsing" setting did nothing).

What puzzles me even more is that this mount visitor to the "rifa" tab ammounts to 1.022 people, and there has been a lot of interactions on it, but yet it seems that this tab is just not visible for some other people.

Comment: Ever managed to find out what was the problem? I'm having the same issue and for the life of me, I can't figure out why the tab isn't displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the tab which is not visible and add it again through your admin login
*_*__*_*___&next=http:url">https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=***_*__*_*___**&next=http:url where ur files are hosted"